# Renaming rows under Specific column to a common name - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column name for "country" and in this column I have 20 or so countries, however they are in many different languages, thus coming up several times in different languages. For example, Switzerland comes up as Suiza, Schweiz, Suisse and Switzerland.

How do I rename the duplicated countries in the "country" column to be under a common name, Switzerland, while also keeping the values in the other columns?

Comment: where do you have the alternate names stored i.e. `Suiza, Schweiz, Suisse` for `Switzerland` ?

Comment: All the names of the countries are under the "country" column. Just in multiple languages

Comment: is there another column in your dataset indicating which language each country name is in or the preferred country name? Are there any other similar/shared values in the dataset?

Comment: I am planning to have all the countries in english, but this column doesn't have similar values to the other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `CASE` statement:

```
df = spark.sql(
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN country IN ('Suiza', 'Schweiz', 'Suisse','Switzerland')
    THEN 'Switzerland'
    WHEN ... -- other translations
    ELSE country
  END AS country,
  ... -- other columns
FROM your_table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mapping table you can join it to your table

```
countryList = [
    ("Suiza",),
    ("Allemagne",),
    ("Schweiz",),
    ("Suisse",),
    ("Switzerland",),
    ("Suisse",),
    ("Suisse",),
    ("Germany",)
    ]

schema = ["country",]
df_countries = spark.createDataFrame(data=countryList, schema = schema)

countryMap = [
    ("Suiza","CH"),
    ("Schweiz","CH"),
    ("Suisse","CH"),
    ("Switzerland","CH"),
    ("Germany","DE"),
    ("Allemagne","DE")
    ]

schema = ["country","unified_country"]
df_map = spark.createDataFrame(data=countryMap, schema = schema)

df_countries.show()
df_map.show()

df_result=(df_countries
          .join(df_map,on="country",how="left")
          )

df_result.show()
```

looks like this

```
+-----------+---------------+
|    country|unified_country|
+-----------+---------------+
|      Suiza|             CH|
|    Schweiz|             CH|
|    Germany|             DE|
|     Suisse|             CH|
|     Suisse|             CH|
|     Suisse|             CH|
|  Allemagne|             DE|
|Switzerland|             CH|
+-----------+---------------+
```